# How can i change a textView position on screen and how to change it's text?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is the textView2 code in my activity_main.xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checking Connection.."
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="47dp"/>
```

In the designer the textView2 is in the middle of the screen not in the center a bit upper from the center but in the middle.

Now i'm trying to change it's text in a real time inside a FOR loop:

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    text.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            text.setText("Checking Connection With Ip: " + ipaddresses[i]);
                                        }
                                    });
                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {



                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response,"UTF-8");



                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }

                                else
                                {

                                }





                        }
                        if (response == null)
                        {
                            text.post(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                    text.setText("Connection Failed");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

The part i added now is:

```
text.post(new Runnable()
                                    {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                            text.setText("Checking Connection With Ip: " + ipaddresses[i]);
                                        }
                                    });
```

Two problems:

When i change here the text of textView2 i need to move textView2 to the left so all the text will be inside the screen.

Second problem is that it dosen't identify the variabl: i

Answer (score 1):

To move the TextView, you have to do this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and to access the i variable, you have to declare it final.

Comment: Where do i add this code of the moving the TextView ? In the place where i change the text ? The place where i want to change the text is inside a loop and i want to move the TextView only once but also only when changing in this place the text.

Comment: Second i can't declare the variable i as final since i declare it as int in the for loop. for (int i =.... if i will do for (final int i = then i will not be able to assign to it(i++)

Comment: You put this code right after you initialize your textview, inside the onClick method. And you can declare the variable i outside the method, on the class scope and it'll work.

Comment: Ok seems to be working with the i but the whole textView2 is jumping to the top up. I wanted it to stay on same height it was only to move it to the left so the whole text will enter the line.

Comment: To keep your textView2 above textView, do this: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, textView.getId()), remember you have to initialize textView as well.